# Swift overriding init in subclass throwing error

Tags: swift

I'm currently testing out my knowledge in terms of initializers and inheritance. However, when I tried overriding the init function of the superclass in my sub class it throws me an error stating, "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass" I hope you guys could help me out thanks!

```
class Employee {
    var name = ""
    var salary = 0
    var role = ""

    init() {

    }

    init(_ name:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.salary = 0
        self.role = "Helpdesk"
    }

    func doWork() {
        print("Currently working hard...")
        salary += 1000
    }
}


class Manager: Employee {

    var teamSize = 0
    var bonus:Int {
        // this is a computed property
        return teamSize * 1000
    }

    override init(_ name:String, _ team:Int) {       // ERROR pops up here**********
        super.init(name)
        self.teamSize = team
    }

    override func doWork() {
        super.doWork()

        print("Currently managing people...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `override` from the `Manager` initializer

Comment: may i know why? @RajeshKumarR

Comment: Super doesn't have `init(_ name:, _ team:)` so you can't override it.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot I really appreciate it :D

Comment: @Desdenova Write than in an answer and collect your prize :)

Comment: @JmSanDiego I *strongly* discourage static initialization of variables like this. What exactly does it mean to have an `let e = Employ()`, where has an empty name, an empty role, and gets paid $0? It's a non-sensical value of `Employee`, but it's one that's fully supported my the model. Good model design would make impossible values like this be actually impossible. Look to `URL` for an example. You *literally* cannot make an illegal string like ("aasdfasdf123") into a `URL`.